# Taking Substring from Column to grab text until 3rd occurrence of '/'

Tags: bash, awk

I have searched everywhere but couldn't quite find the exact similar solution to my problem.

In Bash, I have a file that is tab delimited. It can potentially have several million lines. In the 27th column there is a string of colors which is delimited by a forward slash. My end goal is for the file's 27th column to be trimmed such that only the first three colors stay and the rest of the colors in that column are cut out.

Ie

```
    column1.    column2.    column 3.    colors
        abc.        abc.         abc.    green/yellow/red/orange/blue
```

should become:

```
    column1.    column2.   column 3.   colors
        abc.        abc.        abc.   green/yellow/red
```

I've been trying to accomplish this using awk, but I'm afraid I just can't seem to get it to work. Here was what I attempted:

```
awk 'NR>1 BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {gsub(/^(?:[^\/]*[\/]){2}[^\/]*(.*)/,"",$27); print $0}' ${filename} > "${filename}.tmp" && mv "${filename}.tmp" "${filename}"
```

I'm vastly unfamiliar with regular expressions, and this is just what I can get to work on a regex builder site, but still not sure if that's even correct. Again to clarify, I want all the other columns to remain as they are, but I simply want to trim the color column (column number 27) so that only the first 3 colors remain. This file can get huge so I was hoping to keep this in a single command such as awk if possible so that I'm not slowing things down.

Comment: You might try splitting the 27th column on the '/' character into an array and then printing only portions of the array you need.  Something like:  `split($27,a,"/");  $27=a[1]"/"a[2]"/"a[3]`

Comment: yep, that's what dawg suggested below. I was unaware of the split function in awk. That's super handy and I'll definitely be using this in the future as well. Thanks

Comment: Try `cut -d / -f 1-3` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
$ cat file
column1.    column2.    column 3.   colors
abc.    abc.    abc.    green
abc.    abc.    abc.    green/yellow
abc.    abc.    abc.    green/yellow/red
abc.    abc.    abc.    green/yellow/red/orange/blue
```

You can do:

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
split($4,a,"/")>3{$4=a[1] "/" a[2] "/" a[3]} 1' file
```

With `$4` set to the col you want to change...

If you have variable number of colors and want to print up to `max` you can do:

```
awk  '
BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"; max=3}
split($4,a,"/")>2{
        s=a[1]
        for(i=2; i<=length(a) && i<=max; i++) s=s "/" a[i]
        $4=s
} 1' file
```

With that input, either of these prints:

```
column1.    column2.    column 3.   colors
abc.    abc.    abc.    green
abc.    abc.    abc.    green/yellow
abc.    abc.    abc.    green/yellow/red
abc.    abc.    abc.    green/yellow/red
```

Comment: Interesting, could you explain what that beginning part is doing? The "$4~/\//" portion? I think I understand the rest of it.

Comment: The `$4~/\//` only does the part inside `{...}` if that regex is matched -- if the `$4` has `/` in it anywhere.

Comment: And hope field 4 has at least 2 slashes (3 colors).

Comment: I should have mentioned in my post that the color column can have 0 to unlimited colors, so I may have to mess with it a bit, but I definitely think this is the route that will work. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielCory not only should you have mentioned it. your provided sample input/output should have included multiple rows with different numbers of colors, not just a single row with more than 3.

Answer (score 2):

Given this input file with different numbers of colors in the target column to better test the OPs actual requirements as provided in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75837785/taking-substring-from-column-to-grab-text-until-3rd-occurrence-of#comment133772495_75837898):

```
$ cat file
column1.        column2.        column3.        colors
abc.    abc.    abc.    green/yellow/red/orange/blue
abc.    abc.    abc.    green/yellow/red
abc.    abc.    abc.    green/yellow
abc.    abc.    abc.    green
abc.    abc.    abc.
```

then using GNU awk for the 3rd arg to `match()`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} match($4,"([^/]*/){2}[^/]*",a){$4=a[0]} 1' file
column1.        column2.        column3.        colors
abc.    abc.    abc.    green/yellow/red
abc.    abc.    abc.    green/yellow/red
abc.    abc.    abc.    green/yellow
abc.    abc.    abc.    green
abc.    abc.    abc.
```

or using any POSIX awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} match($4,"([^/]*/){2}[^/]*"){$4=substr($4,1,RLENGTH)} 1' file
column1.        column2.        column3.        colors
abc.    abc.    abc.    green/yellow/red
abc.    abc.    abc.    green/yellow/red
abc.    abc.    abc.    green/yellow
abc.    abc.    abc.    green
abc.    abc.    abc.
```

The above will work no matter how many colors you have in your target column.

Answer (score 0):

If Perl is allowed:

```
$ perl -pe 's@\b(\w+/\w+/\w+).*@$1@' file
    column1.    column2.    column 3.    colors
        abc.        abc.         abc.    green/yellow/red
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but no I don't think perl would be permitted for this.

Answer (score 0):

I want to explain why your attempt failed.

> just what I can get to work on a regex builder site, but still not
> sure if that's even correct

Firstly, there are different *flavors*, see [Regular Expression Engine Comparison Chart](https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/6c933f4a7d713ef712145c5eb94a1816) for overview and comparison which does features what.

```
{gsub(/^(?:[^\/]*[\/]){2}[^\/]*(.*)/,"",$27); print $0}
```

You are attempting to use `(?:regex) (non-capturing group)` as we can learn from linked site `AWK` does use `POSIX ERE` and as chart show it does not support that particular feature.

Answer (score -1):

try this, using perl

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN { $filename = "input.csv"; open($in, "<", $filename) or die "Cannot open $filename: $!"; open($out, ">", "$filename.tmp") or die "Cannot open $filename.tmp: $!"; } chomp; if ($. == 1) { print $out "$_\n"; next; } @fields = split("\t", $_); @colors = split("\/", $fields[26]); $fields[3] = join("\/", @colors[0..3]); print $out join("\t", @fields) . "\n"; END { close $in; close $out; }' input.csv
```

**Output:**

```
column1.    column2.    column 3.   colors
abc.    abc.    abc.    /green/yellow/red
abc.    abc.    abc.    /grewn/yeldow/red
abc.    abc.    abc.    /grecn/yelvow/red
abc.    abc.    abc.    /grezn/yelfow/red
abc.    abc.    abc.    /greqn/yelwow/red
```